# LSTM on 2D Data Event Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, predictive-models

I have multiple signals, which I individually windowed and converted into spectrograms using Fourier transforms. On each signal there is an event "X" at one arbitrary point. I am using CNNs to extract features from each Spectrogram window and then I am planning to use those as an input to my LSTM. Essentialy I am trying to build a predictor of the event "X", but I am not entirely sure how to label my data. What do I feed the LSTM other than the CNN feature vectors (i.e. label vectors? If so, what do these labels have to be?) Moreover, what should I expect as an output. Just to save time, I understand LSTM application in a regressive style, i.e. predicting the next number in a sequence, but I can't get my head around what to expect if I am supplying an LSTM with a Feature Vector that is not "tangible".

Thank you!

Comment: What will your test data look like? Are you going to find if X happened or not for a given series or are you going to specify the time instant of it happened?

Comment: I would like to test both to be honest. Start with finding the occurrence of X given a sequence and then specifying when it happened. I am exploring the data, so both would be useful.